# Java: deploying one method before continuing with the rest

Tags: java, deployment, applet

Hey guys, I'm kinda new to Java.

Lets say I have two methods, spinner() and loadEverything(). I want to execute spinner() first and have it run while loadEverything(), which is kinda heavy, is finishing. I've tried but no matter what I do the applet loads everything before rendering spinner().

Best regards,
Ulrik

Thanks to: baphomet13, sovled my problem.

Comment: Can you post some code? It's a bit hard to understand what you want to do. What do you mean by deploy? Execute?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. A method (which should start with a lower-case letter) can't be "deployed" nor "replaced". It can only be called.

Comment: @Kaj, Yes execute and render to the screen. The code will be meaningless at the moment, will see if I can find something to post though.

Comment: I suggest you have a look at threading. [This](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/threads/threads1.html) is a helpful article about threading in Swing.

Comment: @JB Nizet, naming conventions er merely guidelines not rules. Yes it was stupid of me to use UpperCamelCase in a language as "religious" as the java community.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you want your spinner method to be run in parallel with the loadEverything method. For two methods to be executed in parallel, you need threads. But threads must respect some hard rules when used inside a Swing application or applet. Read [the tutorial on concurrency in Swing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for explanations.

Comment: Thanks for being more specific and helpful than your previous comment. Much appreciated.